# System of ODEs with products

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

How can we solve the system of differential equations

> $\dfrac{df(t)}{dt}=-f(t)h(t), \dfrac{dg(t)}{dt}=-g(t)h(t), \dfrac{dh(t)}{dt}=1-(h(t))^2$

The system does not fall to standard ODE methods.

Comment: Can you solve the last first by SoV and then do the same for the other two?

Comment: Solving the first two we have $f(t) = cg(t)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solve the last ODE for h then plug the solution back in the first two. 
 $h(x)=\dfrac{\exp(2x)-c}{\exp(2x)+c}$